# How I can encode value of 2,5 into DTD

Tags: xml, schema, dtd

My Question is Regarding DTD encoding where as below

```
     <!ELEMENT S (S|zero)>
     <!ELEMENT zero EMPTY>
```

It is encoding zero to stand for 0,
   how we can encode positive integer,
   so what are the encoding of 2,5.

Comment: There are no numeric simple types in DTD. The closest you can get is using a `NMTOKEN`, which allows an alphanumeric character without spaces or special chars. What you are defining in your DTD are complex types (elements) named `<S>` and `<zero>`. If you mean something else, please add more detail and explain your problem more clearly. Add examples of the XML code you want to validate.

Comment: You seem to be using XML to encode Church numerals.  Your problem would appear not to be how to encode fractional values in a DTD but how to represent fractions using Church numerals.  Since Church numerals, by design, represent the natural numbers (*not* just the positive integers), you will need to find a mechanism that goes beyond them to handle rational numbers.  Perhaps you should introduce a division operator?  Once you have the conceptual problem solved, expressing the rules in a DTD should be straightforward.